# Keras MemoryError: alloc failed on Windows

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, keras

I wanted to train my net (image classification, unfortunately on CPU) and I have 71.000 records: 48x48 (gray-scale) images. (when I save it to a numpy array it is 1.4 Gb)

After a few minutes I get this error message:

```
Epoch 1/50
   3200/57419 [>.............................] - ETA: 5381s - loss: 1.9127 - acc: 0.2338Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:/Emotion-Recognition/trainEmotionRecognizer.py", line 68, in <module>
      verbose=1, callbacks=callbacks)
    File "C:\Users\Gabor\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 664, in fit
      sample_weight=sample_weight)
    File "C:\Users\Gabor\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1143, in fit
      initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
    File "C:\Users\Gabor\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 843, in _fit_loop
      outs = f(ins_batch)
    File "C:\Users\Gabor\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\theano_backend.py", line 919, in __call__
      return self.function(*inputs)
    File "C:\Users\Gabor\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 886, in __call__
      storage_map=getattr(self.fn, 'storage_map', None))
    File "C:\Users\Gabor\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\link.py", line 325, in raise_with_op
      reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_trace)
    File "C:\Users\Gabor\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 873, in __call__
      self.fn() if output_subset is None else\
  MemoryError: alloc failed
  Apply node that caused the error: Alloc(TensorConstant{(1L, 1L, 1..1L) of 0.0}, if{shape,inplace}.0, TensorConstant{64}, if{shape,inplace}.2, if{shape,inplace}.3)
  Toposort index: 126
  Inputs types: [TensorType(float32, (True, True, True, True)), TensorType(int64, scalar), TensorType(int64, scalar), TensorType(int64, scalar), TensorType(int64, scalar)]
  Inputs shapes: [(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), (), (), (), ()]
  Inputs strides: [(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), (), (), (), ()]
  Inputs values: [array([[[[ 0.]]]], dtype=float32), array(64L, dtype=int64), array(64L, dtype=int64), array(24L, dtype=int64), array(24L, dtype=int64)]
  Outputs clients: [[if{inplace}(keras_learning_phase, Alloc.0, CorrMM_gradInputs{half, (1, 1), (1, 1)}.0), if{inplace}(keras_learning_phase, CorrMM_gradInputs{half, (1, 1), (1, 1)}.0, Alloc.0)]]

  Backtrace when the node is created(use Theano flag traceback.limit=N to make it longer):
    File "C:\Users\Gabor\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gradient.py", line 1272, in access_grad_cache
      term = access_term_cache(node)[idx]
    File "C:\Users\Gabor\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gradient.py", line 965, in access_term_cache
      output_grads = [access_grad_cache(var) for var in node.outputs]
    File "C:\Users\Gabor\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gradient.py", line 1272, in access_grad_cache
      term = access_term_cache(node)[idx]
    File "C:\Users\Gabor\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gradient.py", line 965, in access_term_cache
      output_grads = [access_grad_cache(var) for var in node.outputs]
    File "C:\Users\Gabor\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gradient.py", line 1272, in access_grad_cache
      term = access_term_cache(node)[idx]
    File "C:\Users\Gabor\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gradient.py", line 1106, in access_term_cache
      new_output_grads)
    File "C:\Users\Gabor\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\op.py", line 700, in L_op
      return self.grad(inputs, output_grads)
    File "C:\Users\Gabor\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\ifelse.py", line 223, in grad
      for i, t in enumerate(ts)])

  HINT: Use the Theano flag 'exception_verbosity=high' for a debugprint and storage map footprint of this apply node.
```

I use my laptop which has *8GB RAM* and when I saw the performance when the training runs and after a while it uses 100% of it.

I have no idea how could I train my net now.

This is the **model structure**:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(1,48,48)))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(6, activation='softmax'))
```

I use a batch size of *64* and the train image size is `(1, 48, 48) with dtype = uint8`

How can I fix this error and train my network?

Comment: Try to use smaller batches

Comment: I also came across this problem recently. Try to restart your python kernel and run model compilation and training once again. There is probably a memory leak in a newest version of Theano

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that *Theano* has memory leak. When I tried to train it with *Tensorflow* as Keras backend it was successful.

So If you has a problem like that, change the backend (watch out for `dim_ordering`)

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the memory requirement oyu can either reduce the size of the model (Dropout also requires memory equal to the previous Convolution layer) or you can reduce the batchsize. Anyways to train such a model on the cpu might take you days if not weeks. I would strongly suggest to calculate this on a gpu if possible.

Comment: I would do that, but unfortunately, I don't have a good GPU (and on Windows I can not reach it) and I can not register to AWS (because I don't have an accepted credit card). As I calculated it would take 3 days to train it on CPU.